# Computing probability for Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, markov-chains

I'm given an infinite Markov chain with state space $\Omega=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ with transition matrix $$P=\begin{pmatrix}p & 1-p & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots\dots \\ p & 0 & 1-p & 0 & 0 &0 & \dots \dots \\ p & 0 &0 &1-p & 0 &0 &\dots\dots \\ p & 0 & 0 &0 &1-p & 0 &\dots\dots \\ \vdots & & \ddots & & \ddots  & & \vdots\end{pmatrix}  $$
That is $$p_{ij}= \begin{cases}p & for & i\in \Omega, j=0 \\ 1-p & if & j=i+1 & i,j\in \Omega \\ 0 & otherwise \end{cases}  $$

I have computed the stationary distribution as $$\pi_k=p(1-p)^k $$ for $k\geq 0$.

Im asked to compute the probability to reach state $0$ after a "long time" assuming that we start at state $i\geq 3$. The answer is apparently $p(1-p)^2$, but I dont understand why? Could anyone help me out?

My own interpetation of the question is to compute $$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_{n+1}=0 | X_n \geq 3) $$ Which I cant manage to get to $p(1-p)^2$.

I appreciate help

Comment: Note that $P(X_{n+1} = 0 |  X_n \ge k ) = p$ for all $k$. Perhaps you are thinking about $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n = 0 | X_0 \ge 3)$.

Comment: @HansEngler The problem is, I didnt really specifiy it. But the exercise is about listeners calling a radio show, answering a question.

If the answer is wrong he/she wins nothing, and a CD which he/she could have won is put "on hold". If the answer is correct, he/she wins the CD, plus all CDs that are currently "on hold". Where each caller gives a correct answer with probability p, independently for all callers.

And the question is "Compute the probability that, after the show has been going on for a long time, any given caller wins three CDs or more."

Comment: The Markov chain $\{X_k\}$  models the number of CDs on hold just before caller $k$ gives his/her answer.

Comment: @HansEngler So I'm thinking that the caller that calls the show, must be calling in when there is at least 3 CDs "put on hold". And from there on I need to calculate the probability that the caller answers correctly and wins all CDs that are "on hold", which should only be able to happen in the next time step?

Comment: Looks like a geometric distribution with the 3rd trial being a success

Comment: @Elsa How do I derive to the answer in tems of Markov chains?

Comment: It's probably easiest to convince yourself of the correct answer without using Markov chains. A caller wins three or more CDs if (s)he answers correctly and the two previous callers answer incorrectly. The probability for this is $p(1-p)^2$.

Comment: @HansEngler But in that case, isn't that the probability of winning only exactly 3 CDs since its exactly 2 previous callers answering incorrectly? And not of winning 3 or more?

Comment: The winning caller will win exactly 3 CDs if the two previous callers lost and the the one before won, probability $p^2(1-p)^2$. Returning to the original problem: Have you covered time-reversible Markov chains yet?

Comment: @HansEngler So $p(1-p)^2$ is the probability of at least winning 3 CDs, since the 2 previous callers answered incorrectly, but we dont know if the caller before the first one answered right/wrong, which means it could be more than potentially 3?